# Scala removing IF Else statement and write in a functional way

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming

Let's say I have the following tuple

```
(colType, colDocV)
```

Where colType is a boolean and colDocV is a String
Depending on those two values, I will apply some chunk of code that applies transformations to a Dataframe.

Now, this code works. However, I am not convinced this is the proper way to write functional programming code.
I don't know which of these 3 approaches will improve the quality of the code and remove all if-if else-else :
Should I apply some kind of design pattern and which one?
Should I use some kind of pattern matching? 
Should I use some anonymous function?

```
if (colDocV) {
  val newCol = udf(UDFHashCode.udfHashCode).apply(col(columnName))
  dataframe.withColumn(columnName, newCol)
} else if (colType.contains("string") || colType.contains("text")) {
  val newCol = udf(Entropy.stringEntropyFunc).apply(col(columnName)).cast(DoubleType)
  dataframe.withColumn(columnName, newCol)
} else if (colType.contains("date")) {
  val newCol = udf(DateUtils.getTimeAsDoubleFunc).apply(col(columnName)).cast(DoubleType)
  dataframe.withColumn(columnName, newCol)
} else if (colType.contains("long")) {
  dataframe.withColumn(columnName, dataframe(columnName).cast(DoubleType) )
} else {
  dataframe.drop(columnName) //Dropping column that cannot be processed
}
```

Comment: There is nothing "non-functional" about using an `if-else` expression. The better thing to do would be to relay on types instead of strings, but that's a constraint you have by the underlying infrastructure (dataframes in Spark). Perhaps using `DataSet[T]` instead with strongly typed schema (in the form a case class) would reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He's using an if-statement, not an expression, which arguably is non-functional since it relies entirely on side effects.

Comment: @Carcigenicate If we're going to be accurate, there is no if *statement* in Scala, it's an *expression*. Other than that, what side effect are you talking about?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov He's not assigning  the result of the `if`, so even if it *is* an expression, it's being used as a statement. And I was thinking that `newCol` wasn't local to the if. Reassigning it would have been a side effect.

Comment: The `if-else` expression in itself has no side effect, it's a tool. He is using it to return a value, so it is definitely used as an expression. If there was an effect inside the Boolean generating method, then that would be a different case, but it isn't. I often see people going nuts just to avoid a simple `if-else` clause and I really don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `match` statement and a bunch of regexps.

```
val str = ".*(?:string|text).*".r
val date = ".*date.*".r
val long = ".*long.*".r

def col(tuple: (Boolean, String)) = tuple match {
  case (true, _) => Some(udf(...))
  case (_, str()) => Some(udf(...))
  case (_, date()) => Some(udf(...))
  case (, long()) => Some(udf(...))
    case _ => None
}
col(colType -> colDocv)
 .fold(dataframe.drop(columnName)) { newCol => 
    dataframe.withColumn(columnName, newCol)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I understand from  your question following can be a solution using `match case`

```
def callUdf(colDocV: String, colType: Boolean, dataframe: DataFrame) = (colDocV, colType) match {
  case x if (x._1.contains("string") || x._1.contains("text")) => dataframe.withColumn(columnName, udf(Entropy.stringEntropyFunc).apply(col(columnName)).cast(DoubleType))
  case x if (x._1.contains("date")) => dataframe.withColumn(columnName, udf(DateUtils.getTimeAsDoubleFunc).apply(col(columnName)).cast(DoubleType))
  case x if (x._1.contains("long")) => dataframe.withColumn(columnName, dataframe(columnName).cast(DoubleType) )
  case _ => dataframe.drop(columnName)

}
```